# Autowired a method from the @Config class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have class for the SOAP configuration provided below:

Comment: Your OrderingClient seems to be not a Spring component, by the way your class BrinkWebserviceClient is abstract and I do not find the brinkOrderingWebServiceTemplate creation. The WebServiceGatewaySupport is not a class on which Spring creates a dinamyc-implementation.

Comment: Okay. I added the `@Component` annotation atop of the `OrderingClient` class and the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `@Component` annotation to the OrderingClient.